# Lots of file are getting generated automatically in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

**How to stop these files from getting generated ? so during commit they wont show up **

when I change in any file then along with changed files lots of other files are getting generated which am totally unaware about.
Some of the files are my class files but generated one are having $ or something after that .
Check please some of files below .
Most of these are not my class files.

````
 1.androidResources
 2.app-debug.apk
 3.build-history.bin
 4.buildOutputCleanUp.lock
 5.call-attributes.tab
 6.call-fq-name-to-source.tab
 7.claases.dex
 8.clientsListfragmentCompanion.class
 9.ClientsListFragment$fetchClientNames@1.class
10.looksups.tab.values.s
11.looksups.tab.values.at
12.last-build.bin```
````

````
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.evolutsoft.businesscalculator"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'io.apisense:rhino-android:1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

}```
````

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how can i stop these files from getting generation so during commit they wont show up

Comment: Are they generated inside `build` directory or outside it?

Comment: yes most of them are under build but some are under graddle directory too

Comment: `build` and `.gradle` directories are for temporary build files. You shouldn't commit any files from these directories, they should be entirely ignored in `.gitignore` file.

Comment: You cannot stop the creation of these files. They are required for the project.
So that they do not get into the commit, need to set up the correct .gitignore file.

Comment: and how can i do it ?

Comment: can you post a method  in here  ?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514

Comment: You can also search for ".gitignore android"

Comment: BTW, you sounded like the main problem for you with these files was that you considered them unrelated to your project. If you already committed other files from `build`/`.gradle` then I suggest removing them all from the git. They shouldn't be in the repository.